# Windows 8 - Cordova - navigator.camera.getPicture

Tags: javascript, windows-8, cordova, blob, cordova-3

We are in the process of porting our HTML application to Windows 8 using Cordova/Phonegap 3.1.0. Most of it runs fine; however when we take a photo using the FILE_URI navigation, we receive what initially looks like a blob, but is just a string (I believe).

An example string I get back when using the following code, could be:

```
blob:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Using:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(success, failure, {
    quality: 40,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit: false,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 320,
    targetHeight: 240
});
```

Comment: Obviously the GUID returned is not an empty GUID - but an actual GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this does not seem to be supported:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Text data is supported by all platforms listed below. Text is encoded as UTF-8 before being written to the filesystem. *Some* platforms also support binary data, which can be passed in as either an ArrayBuffer or a Blob.

**Supported Platforms**

**Text and Binary Support:**

Android

iOS

**Text-only Support:**

BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 5.0 and higher)

Windows Phone 7 and 8

Windows 8

I am working on a WinJS workaround with platform detection.  I will update this post if it is possible.